# How do make MudBlazor component work like normal HTML elements

Tags: blazor-server-side, mudblazor

[image][image][image]I am using Blazor & MudBlazor components, I am having problem with MudBlazor, when I use MudText to print values in a for loop, it prints the final value '5' for all values of the loop. However, when I use HTML element like paragraph tag, it works fine. I want MudText to work like normal Html. See attached.

see this on the repo

https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QOGPbOvlUMTlQUoh

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign a variable inside the scope. Something like this:

```js
for(int 1=0; i<5; i++){
var something = @i.ToString();
<MudText Typo="Typo.h6">@something</MudText>
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).